# removing the list container <ul> from the custom menu output

Tags: menus

any suggestions on how to get rid of ***ul*** tag wrapped around ***li*** tags in custom menu here at

http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/careers/

the custom menu is outputted with nested  tags around like

```
<ul id="menu-home" class="navLeft"><li><a href="http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/careers/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/careers/?page_id=18">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to take out the  tags and already passed the container => false parameter before outputting custom menu as mentioned at wordpress codex, below is code again.

```
 $args = array(
   'menu' => 'home_menu',
   // 'sort_column' => '',
    'container' => 'false',
    //'container_id'=>'myID',
    'menu_class' => 'navLeft',
    'walker' => new my_walker()
);


wp_nav_menu( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `container` argument controls what is one level higher - around `<ul>`.

What you need is `items_wrap` argument that controls the list wrap and defaults to `<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>`.

[Removing the ul wrap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Removing_the_ul_wrap) in Codex gives following example:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) );
```

Comment: Hi @Rarst okay I went ahead and added the new argument 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ,

still same ***ul*** tags wrapped around

Comment: @Adi I am not sure what the reason might be... Check that you are modifying correct lines of code, that it's uploaded to site ok and that page is not getting cached if you use some form of caching.

Comment: Got it working now !